# Modifying spreadsheet gem (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet

I have an excel file "stores.xls" with one worksheet, two columns and 10 rows.
I am trying to edit the second column with Spreadsheet gem in Ruby, and I don't get any error during the process, but when I try to open the file I get "format is not valid" and sometimes "block in biff_version. Unknown BIFF version".

Any ideas?

```
require 'spreadsheet'

book = Spreadsheet.open 'stores.xls'
sheet = book.worksheet 0 

sheet.each do |row|
    nameStore = row[0]
    source = nameStore + ".com"
    row[1] = source
end

book.write 'stores.xls'
```

Comment: Seems this is an existing issue with spreadsheet gem https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

You can spend time fixing this error, but you might run into more

If this spreadsheet is important I really do recommend converting to a template using Microsoft XML. It shouldn't take more than 15 minutes

[Railscast #362](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel).